# MySQL table vertically output

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, while-loop, html-table

How do I get my mysql records in an html table vertical with an mysql while or for clause? If I do it with the while clause I only get the horizontal line output.

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM kalender ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = mysql_query($select);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I want it like this

```
-Monday-  -Tuesday-  -Wednesday-  -Thursday-  -Friday-
Monday 1   Tuesday 1  Wednesday 1  Thursday 1  Friday 1
Monday 2   Tuesday 2  Wednesday 2  Thursday 2  Friday 2
Monday 3   Tuesday 3  Wednesday 3  Thursday 3  Friday 3
```

not like this...

```
-Monday-  -Tuesday-  -Wednesday-  -Thursday-  -Friday-
 Monday 1  Monday 2   Monday 3     Monday 4    Monday 5
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: But i want to do it with mysl_* functiosn because i learned with it

Comment: Not directly related, but ordering by ID is almost never a good solution. Don't you have something like date or a timestamp stored in each record?

Comment: *It doesn't matter* @NilsBlaumer. As soon as someone updates your server all of your code will break.

Comment: yeag i have the date

Comment: @JayBlanchard so i have to change my code?

Comment: You *should* change your code.

Comment: okay i will change it sooner

Comment: Please add the schema of your table, and show some actual example data.

Comment: i build it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1235/2

Comment: and like this schema i want to do a query and populate my table

Comment: okay sorry but i didnt find an approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT * FROM kalender ORDER BY RIGHT(name,1) ASC, id DESC";
```

**UPDATE1** According to the fiddle you've provided: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1235/2

You have 5 columns in your table `ForgeRock`, so you should just change your php code to:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM kalender ";
$query = mysql_query($select);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Monday']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['Tuesday']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['Wednesday']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['Thursday']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['Friday']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

But I don't trust your fiddle, because there is no `name` column. But you have it in OP. And table name in OP is `kalender`. Maybe that is not important, but questions are there.

Comment: And then? do you have an example for a while or for loop?

Comment: I somehow doubt that the values given in the example represent real-world values as that would make the whole database unnecessary. And it breaks at `10`. Either way, an explanation would be nice, just one line of code doesn't really make an answer.

Comment: Since there is no good data samples in OP I have no idea what you really need. If you provide more data and explanation I can help with better solution and explanation. But so far, it is just visual analysis of presentation you post. For example, visually we have one table= 5x3 but in your php code I see that you have only table=1xn. So I have no idea where is truth

Comment: @Alex I definitely agree with you there :-)

Comment: I want a calendar, that show each meeting for Monday in the table column foreach meeting a new row. and this for Monday to Friday. Understood?

Comment: no. I don't. Show data samples and table structure and expected result.